# How many days between two dates C++

Tags: c++, date, date-arithmetic

I have a program that uses two functions I have defined inside a class. My class works fine, but my program always returns an amount that is some amount of days off. There is more error when the dates are farther apart. My code is designed to in one function calculate the total amount of days since 1582, and another function subtracts the higher amount from the lesser. Where am I getting the error from? I know it may not be the most efficient way to do things (cpu wise) but can someone find where my logic is messed up? This accounts for leap years as well. I have been checking my program against a website http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html

```
int Date::totalDays()
{
    int totalDays = 0;
    int daysInMonth[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,31,31,30,31};
    totalDays += day;
    for (int i = month-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        totalDays += daysInMonth[i];
    }
    for (int i = year-1; i > 1582; i--)
    {
        if(year % 100 == 0)
        {
            if(year % 400 == 0)
                totalDays += 366;
            else
                totalDays += 365;
        }
        else
        {
            if(year % 4 == 0)
                totalDays += 366;
            else
                totalDays += 365;
        }
    }
    return totalDays;
}

int Date::daysBetween(Date other)
{
    if (this->totalDays() > other.totalDays())
        return this->totalDays() - other.totalDays();
    else
        return other.totalDays() - this->totalDays();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Calendars have been modified over the years.  You will need to use the adjustment in your program.

Comment: Are you aware of the _[C time functions](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/)_?

Comment: If the answer below doesn't fix your problem, please write an MCVE.  (I started to debug this myself, but why recreate your code when all you have to do is post it?)

Comment: I am aware of C time functions, but the purpose of this lesson is to create classes, not to use existing libraries. And I didn't think the Gregorian calendar has been modified since 1853. That is why my program does not account for anything before that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem 1:

```
int daysInMonth[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,31,31,30,31};
```

should be

```
int daysInMonth[]={0,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
//                                           ^^
```

---

Problem 2:

if the current `year` is a leap-year, and `month` is greater than 2, you'll also need to add one day to account for February 29th of the current year.

Comment: Oh my goodness... such a simple mistake.
There is still a small amount of error somewhere though. That reduced the error by a lot though.